# Can I send OnMouseDown() event elsewhere?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to make a pretty simple memory game (ie, table of cards, player flips over two at a time trying to find a match) in unity.  The way I've formatted it is that I have a CardScript attached to the cards and a script attached to the board that holds all the cards, sends messages to rotate over, clears when a match is made, ect ect.  However, I've hit a snag.  I'm using `void OnMouseDown()` in the CardScript to know when it should flip, but I don't know how to make the board aware that this has happened.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need for communication between objects is a reference. To get a reference you usually just keep a variable like this:

```
 MyScript reference = new MyScript();
```

However, that won't always work in Unity because you can't use `new` on MonoBehaviours. So you need another way.

You find the reference! You can use this:

```
 MyScript reference = GameObject.Find("GameObjectName").GetComponent<MyScript>();
```

Once you have the reference just make function calls.

```
reference.foo();
```

Comment: Thank you!  I managed to do this by passing a reference to the object when the Card is instantiated.  Well Played.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to send message across scripts. This is what you have to do:

**Script1.cs**

```
public void checky()
{
  print("you touched my card");
}
```

**Script2.cs**

```
private Script1 otherScript; // we need Script1
void OnMouseDown()
{
  otherScript = new Script1(); // new instance of Script1
  otherScript.checky(); // accessing public method of Script1
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: is it possible to send it both ways and maintain the fact that they're talking to the same instance of each other?

Comment: Yes it is possible. repeat the same process in script1 then they will have nice chatting :)

Comment: Understand that your solution will only work if `Script1` does not inherit from  `MonoBehaviour`. If it does, you can't use the new keyword to get instance. `GetComponent` is the solution